# Programmatically verify a taxonomy term has been added to a node

Tags: 8, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I'm currently checking the node type and status, using the following code.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('type', 'content_page')
  ->execute();

foreach ($query as $nid) {
  // …
}
```

I need to know whether a taxonomy term has been added to a node. I don't need to know the name or ID of that term, which is a taxonomy term from the *Group Required* vocabulary.

What code should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that your tag will always be in one specific field, you can use the [exists()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Aexists/9.2.x) method on your query to only fetch ids of entities where that field has a value, i.e. is not empty.

For example:

```
$entity_ids = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->getQuery()
  ->condition('type', 'content_page')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  // Check if field has a non empty value
  ->exists('MY_TAXONOMY_REF_FIELD')
  // exists('MY_FIELD') is equivalent to condition('MY_FIELD', NULL, 'IS NOT NULL')
  ->execute();
```

Then, load your entities:

```
$entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadMultiple($entity_ids);
```

Comment: Brilliant, works a treat, many thanks sonfd :-)